# Wrap textarea content with html tags

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I'm using the following form to save text files on server:

```
<form action="***.php" method="post">
   <textarea class="chrr" name="text" placeholder="Text" required></textarea>
   <button type="submit">SAVE</button>
</form>
```

With the following javascript code, I correct the textarea input:

```
const form = document.forms[0];
const string = document.getElementsByClassName("chrr");

form.oninput = () => {
   string[0].value = correct(string[0].value);
};

function correct(string) {
   string = string.replace(/  +/g, ' ');
   string = string.replace(/—|–/g, '-');
   string = string.replace(/‘|’/g, "'");
   string = string.replace(/“|”/g, '"');
   string = string.replace(/…/g, '...');
   return string;
};
```

Now I would like to wrap every single text line with "p" tags. So, if I paste in the textarea:

```
First line...
Second line...
Third line...
```

The text should automatically become:

```
<p>First line...</p>
<p>Second line...</p>
<p>Third line...</p>
```

How can I achieve this result with pure JavaScript (no jQuery)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the string with `\n`, then map the string to wrap that with the element (*p*). Finally join them:

```js
var str = `First line...
Second line...
Third line...`;

str = str.split('\n').map(s => `<p>${s}</p>`).join('\n');
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!